# JSTL string comparison always returns false

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying string comparison with

```
<c:if test="${dept eq 'account'}"></c:if>
```

But this always returns `false`. I check the dept variable had the value `'account'`. I also tried like this

```
<c:if test="${dept == 'account'}"></c:if>
```

This also returns `false`.

But if I use the java code like this then it works fine

```
<%
if(dept.equals("account")){

blah blah blah
}

%>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "returns false". Are you sure your `<c:if>` tags are actually being executed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The symptoms indicate that you've declared it in the *scriptlet* scope, not in the EL scope. *Scriptlets* and EL doesn't share the same scope. EL uses under the covers [`PageContext#findAttribute()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute(java.lang.String)) to resolve the variable. Put `dept` in one of the page, request, session or application scopes. Which one to choose depends on the sole purpose of `dept` itself. I'd start with the request scope. E.g. in a servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("dept", dept);
```

This way it'll be available in EL by `${dept}`.

After all, best is to avoid using *scriptlets* [completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). Java code belongs in Java classes, not in JSP files.

Comment: Excellent!! This is the perfect answer. Thanks a lot for your time. This is working fine. I think EL was not able to find the dept variable in any scope. As soon as I put it in request scope it starts working fine.